# How to show all records in Spark DataFrame by method .show()?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, show

Assume that I want to see all records of a PySpark DataFrame using [show()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.show.html).

Show() has a parameter `n` that controls number of records to be shown. Is there any way that I can show all records of the DataFrame?

Comment: why don't you simply use `collect` then ? What is your actual problem ? Is it really on `show` or you want a way to see all your data ?

Comment: I want to see all data after applying transformation on dataset to check the results.

Comment: then just use collect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should work fine for you:

df.show(df.count(),False)